# about SQL query different sorting order using two columns

Tags: sql

i have two columns in my table like first_name, last_name 
i need data who are have JHON name both in first_name and Last_name with order like

```
first_name   last_name
Jhon         Ashosh
Jhon         Billa
Jhon         Chowdary

Asthosh      Jhon
Bandla       Jhon
Mehon        Jhon
```

like that above i need output 
note: first i need who has first_name Jhon with last_name sorting order 
      second first_name sorting order with who has Jhon in last_name with one single query

Comment: Which SQL engine are you using? You have tags for MySQL, SQL Server, and Oracle. This is important to know.

Comment: I removed those tags, letting OP start over and tag just one!

Comment: using oracle sql we can get

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, assuming your db table is named my_table

```
SELECT * FROM my_table 
WHERE first_name ='Jhon' OR last_name='Jhon'
ORDER BY last_name, first_name
```

**UPDATE:**

```
SELECT last_name, first_name
FROM (
    SELECT 1 setNum, last_name, first_name
    FROM Users
    WHERE last_name = 'Jhon'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 setNum, last_name, first_name
    FROM Users
    WHERE first_name = 'Jhon'
) mergedTable
ORDER BY setNum, (CASE WHEN 1 THEN first_name END), (CASE WHEN 2 THEN last_name END);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this push the name Jhon Smith to the bottom of the list? Maybe it'll  work for the OP, but it doesn't sound like what was asked for.

Comment: Your query gives output who has first_name and last_name is Jhon but i need output with sorting order like below 
first_name   last_name
Jhon         Ashosh
Jhon         Billa
Jhon         Chowdary

Asthosh      Jhon
Bandla       Jhon
Mehon        Jhon

did u find how do i want output when first_name is Jhon the second_name will get sorting order and when last_name is jhon it will get sorting first_name in one single query both

Comment: You said in your question that you need data that has first_name is 'Jhon' or last_name is 'Jhon'.

Comment: Hmm okay now am asking i need output what i have mentioned in my last comment if u know please comment if u doesn't understand my require please let me know i will explain u what i want

Comment: @Nag So let me clarify your question. You need to get all the records with first_name = Jhon or last_name = Jhon? And, you want them to be ordered by Last Name first then by first name?

Comment: Or you want to list all the records with Jhon as last name first before the records with Jhon as first name?

Comment: i want who are first_name and last_name is 'Jhon' along with                    first i need who has first_name is 'Jhon' and that last_name should be order  next last_name is Jhon and that first_name should be order,    is it okay now ?

Comment: @artsylar, seems like Good example Thank you

Comment: @Nag please choose the one that answers your question best so it can help others also who check your question.

Answer (score 0):

For your case, you could use this:

```
select 
    first_name, last_name
from
    table_name
where 
    first_name = 'Jhon' or last_name = 'Jhon' 
order by
    case when first_name = 'Jhon' then last_name end
    ,case when last_name = 'Jhon' then first_name end;
```

P/S: I have a little confusing about why above solution work equal with this :

```
select 
    first_name, last_name
from
    table_name
where 
    first_name = 'Jhon' or last_name = 'Jhon' 
order by
    case when first_name = 'Jhon' then 0 else 1 end
    ,case when first_name = 'Jhon' then last_name end
    ,case when last_name = 'Jhon' then first_name end;
```

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL:

```
  ORDER BY first_name='Jhon' DESC, last_name, first_name
```

For Oracle:

```
  ORDER BY DECODE(first_name,'Jhon',0,1), last_name, first_name
```

For SQL Server

```
  ORDER BY IIF(first_name='Jhon',0,1), last_name, first_name
```

For a more portable, ANSI-standard solution:

```
  ORDER BY CASE first_name WHEN 'Jhon' THEN 1 END, last_name, first_name
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to ensure ordering of the output so that:

1. All first names of 'Jhon' are at the top
2. All last names of 'Jhon' are at the bottom
3. The unlikely name 'Jhon Jhon' appears in both

then with generic SQL (i.e. no use of CTEs for example) you can do this:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, 1 as name_order
FROM my_table
WHERE first_name = 'Jhon'
UNION ALL
SELECT first_name, last_name, 2
FROM my_table
WHERE last_name = 'Jhon'
ORDER BY
  name_order,
  first_name,
  last_name
```

Comment: First table should be order by last_name

Comment: First table _is_ order by last_name.  The entire UNION ALL set gets ordered by the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: This is an interesting approach and I don't think it deserves a down-vote.

Comment: Ya Thank you for giving good approach but i don't prefer multiple query's to get i think so it is possible in one single query if you get any idea using one single query please post once again thank you

Comment: Depends on whether you want 'Jhon Jhon' to show up once or twice. If you just want it once, then the answer by Artsyler is sufficient. If, on the other hand, you want 'Jhon Jhon' to show up twice, then you either need a UNION ALL or a FULL OUTER JOIN, the latter of which would be prohibitively expensive. Also, keep in mind my query is one query. UNION ALL is valid syntax in SQL-92 for returning combined result sets

Comment: i mean multiple query's means two SELECT statements are available for that query, First it will execute first SELECT statement next second SELECT statement after that combine it will run it's burden on my optimizer and server that is am saying, anyhow that's fine thank you so much